# Using GIS / Map inside c# WPF

Tags: c#, wms, wpf, mapping

How could i create e mapping applications that displays a custom map from this URL: 
(Capabilties with a mapview) 
http://openwms.statkart.no/skwms1/wms.sjo_hovedkart2?request=GetCapabilities&Service=WMS

inside c# with WPF controls.

It would be nice if there was some full feature map libraries so i could add pinpoints to certain Long,lats e.e (Like Openlayers for Javascript)

Google / bing maps API cannot be used as you are not allowed to replace their maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esri's Runtime for WPF [supports WMS layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#//017000000084000000).

It is not free, but the ArcGIS Silverlight SDK is  and has many of the same capabilities.  So you may want to try the Silverlight SDK in [Out-of-browser mode](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/out-of-browser/), which is similar to running a WPF app.  You need to set up a [proxy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer~ProxyUrl.html) though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have too much experience in C# and WPF, but I think there should be such controls as webview or whatever where you can display a web page or a map. Define map operations using OpenLayers with javascript and hook them to C# functions.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it myself but [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) should be able to handle a WMS layer and render it in WPF using a `WindowsFormsHost`. See [Tutorial - Example 3: Adding a WMS-layer to the map](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorial%20-%20Example%203%3a%20Adding%20a%20WMS-layer%20to%20the%20map).

Also check out [Mapsui](http://mapsui.codeplex.com/) which is a port of SharpMap to WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be a fully WPF solution? If not then you can use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control and then you can use Google maps, Bing maps or any other web GIS api.